# WYSIWYG HTML Editor for Server Side Blazor

Tags: blazor, html-editor, blazor-server-side

Does anyone know of a WYSIWYG HTML editor control like CKEditor or the one in the Syncfusion package that works with the **released Server Side Blazor**?
Since it's for production environment, Client Side Blazor, where we don't even know a release date yet, is not an option...
I'm quite new to Blazor, so if you have a solution, preferable one that makes one of the above mentioned controls working, please post three our four lines more so that even a newbie understands it :)

Comment: if this question is so dump, answering it would be as easy as simply downvoting. Very helpful

Comment: Your question is not dumb.  Unfortuantely, SO is not the home for such a question.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Comment: I posted code for a bind-able component that I put together to get TinyMCE working with Blazor here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62091603/1026576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after digging long enough through the documentation, I found the solution for the Syncfusion component.
In case someone else has this problem: [Getting started with Syncfusion in Blazor](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/getting-started/vs-blazor-server/)

Answer (score 5):

While I haven't used this component, I've used several other of the Blazored components and really like them. This one uses Quill under the hood so gives you a rich-text editor that handles HTML.

[Blazored TextEditor](https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor)

Answer (score 2):

Blazorise richtextedit is free for community license. You dont need to get a license online.

https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/richtextedit